# How to optimise this query?

Tags: sql-server, optimization

there're 1 million records in jobs table. the execution time for the following query is 30 secs. The query is not elegant and it will return the number of records fit the criteria. Please help me with optimisation.

```
DECLARE @MaxIdValue varchar(100)
DECLARE @SerchFilter varchar(100) = 'test'
DECLARE @TotalRowCount int = ( SELECT 
Count(*) AS [RowCount]
FROM 
[Jobs]
INNER JOIN [Sites] ON [Jobs].[SiteId] = [Sites].[Id]  
INNER JOIN [JobStatusHistory] ON [Jobs].[JobStatusHistoryId] = [JobStatusHistory].[Id]  
INNER JOIN [JobStatuses] ON [JobStatusHistory].[StatusId] = [JobStatuses].[Id]  
INNER JOIN [JobTypes] ON [Jobs].[JobTypeId] = [JobTypes].[Id]  
LEFT JOIN [Customers] ON [Jobs].[CustomerId] = [Customers].[Id]  
LEFT JOIN [Priorities] ON [Jobs].[PriorityId] = [Priorities].[Id]  
LEFT JOIN [TaskTypes] ON [Jobs].[TaskTypeId] = [TaskTypes].[Id]  
LEFT JOIN [Areas] ON [Sites].[AreaId] = [Areas].[Id]  
WHERE
( 
 [Sites].[Active]=1
 AND 
   (
    [Jobs].[OwnedByCompanyId]=18
      OR  
    [Jobs].[OwnedByCompanyId] = 0)
      AND 
    [Jobs].[Active]=1
   ) 
 AND 
   ( 
  [Customers].[Name] LIKE '%'+@SerchFilter+'%'
 OR 
   [Sites].[Name] LIKE  '%'+@SerchFilter+'%'
   OR 
 [Sites].[Address1] LIKE  '%'+@SerchFilter+'%'
    OR 
  [Sites].[Postcode] LIKE  '%'+@SerchFilter+'%'
 OR 
  [Sites].[UPRN] LIKE  '%'+@SerchFilter+'%'
 OR 
 [Sites].[Contact] LIKE  '%'+@SerchFilter+'%'
     OR 
 [Sites].[Telephone] LIKE  '%'+@SerchFilter+'%'
   OR 
 [Sites].[Work] LIKE  '%'+@SerchFilter+'%'
 OR 
  [Sites].[MobileNumber] LIKE  '%'+@SerchFilter+'%'
  OR 
  [Areas].[Description] LIKE  '%'+@SerchFilter+'%'
    OR 
   [Jobs].[Id] LIKE  '%'+@SerchFilter+'%'
  OR 
  [Jobs].[OrderNumber] LIKE  '%'+@SerchFilter+'%'
   OR 
   [Jobs].[Description_PlainText] LIKE  '%'+@SerchFilter+'%'
  OR 
   [Jobs].[JobNumber] LIKE  '%'+@SerchFilter+'%'
  OR 
  [JobTypes].[Description] LIKE  '%'+@SerchFilter+'%'
   OR 
  [TaskTypes].[Description] LIKE  '%'+@SerchFilter+'%'
     OR 
   [Priorities].[Description] LIKE  '%'+@SerchFilter+'%'
    ) 
  )
```

Comment: What DataType are defined for each field? Like are the Description-fields text or varchar fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use more Indexes & Full Text Catalog.

If you're using MS SQL 2008 you can check for missing indexes in the execution plan. Also from here you can see why it's taking that long.

Answer (score 1):

The optimization would be of that to replace the `'%'+@SerchFilter+'%'` with `@SerchFilter+'%'`.

The where clause `'%'+@SerchFilter+'%'` prevents the usage of the index seek.

EDIT:

Do you really need to filter after all those fields at once? If it is not a number why bothering searching in the `Telephone` field for insance.

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or above you might consider using the [FullText-Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx).

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I just removed '%'+@SerchFilter+'%' it is still 30 secs to finish executing. I'll have a read of the fulltext-search.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your join columns are suitably indexed, I suspect the problem lies with the numerous LIKEs. These are quite an expensive DB operation unfortunately.

Having done something similar, I believe you might be able to get slightly better performance by doing something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE COL1 + COL2 + COL3 + COL4 + COL5 LIKE '%SEARCH%'
```

Rather than:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE 
COL1 LIKE '%SEARCH%' 
OR COL2 LIKE '%SEARCH%'
OR COL3 LIKE '%SEARCH%'
OR COL4 LIKE '%SEARCH%'
OR COL5 LIKE '%SEARCH%'
```

Comment: that's only if all those columns are NOT NULL.

Comment: As they were in my case. If any fields are nullable, you'd obviously need an ISNULL or COALESCE here...

Comment: Now I have a basic understanding of full text index, regarding to what i read from msdn, i got some questions.